# Iptables rule do not drop all packets [UDP Filter]

Tags: server, kernel, iptables, firewall

I have big problem.. I run cs1.6 game server there was one who flood my UDP port "27015" with many packets. I get these packets and analyzed it and then managed to put rule to block these packets. I depend on that all his packets have common error so i drop it all. But the problem is not all packets get dropped. It goes like:

```
80834 packets captured
2247497 packets received by filter
2166625 packets dropped by kernel
```

His all packets come from same port so i tried also to drop all data comes from this port and same some of it still can pass.

Still some packets can go 2% still go through the firewall and this cause some ping problems for my players. How this can be solved? What can cause this? Why not all packets get dropped?

Output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 51734251 packets, 3238696958 bytes)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 11847045 packets, 3735872961 bytes)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your example packet numbers look like summary output from tcpdump, which has nothing to do with what iptables is doing. If you want help with your issue, we will need to see your entire iptables rule set, preferably with the packets counters. i.e. `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L`. For tcpdump to be dropping so many packets, suggests that your server is heavily loaded.

Comment: This is the rule i uses to block all packets coming from 27015 port. And still packets can come... So you need more information?`iptables -A PREROUTING -t raw -p udp --sport 27015 -j DROP`

Comment: This is summery while attacking just in 5 seconds i get all these: `7047 packets captured
200435 packets received by filter
193382 packets dropped by kernel
`

Comment: Well, I would do this: `iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p udp --dport 27015 -j DROP`. The "NEW" state check is so that you can get a return packet if your system used that port, but would require an earlier "RELATED, ESTABLISHED" bypass. And, again, the tcpdump summary has nothing to do with what is going on in iptables. See the man pages for tcpdump. Your system is so overloaded that the kernel is finding the tcpdump buffers full most of the time and therefore missing the packets. I repeat that we can not really help without more detailed information.

Comment: Are you using the "-n" option with your tcpdump command, so as to prevent a lot of wasted time doing DNS lookups?

Comment: Hello Doug, Thanks for response. So now with your command it will drop all packets? All that i need to block all packets coming from this port "27015" and my server run at same port "27015" UDP. I uses the rule i give but still some packets come also i try this `iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 27015 -j DROP` still some can come my tcpdump command is using -n yest: `tcpdump -n udp dst port 27015`

Comment: I give you the tcpdump information just to tell you how much it's loaded at normal when normal players send/recieve packets it's never so high like that. So why still some packets pass? What can i do is there is better Pre place to put the rule in? Maybe i should ask my hoster or? Thanks.

Comment: I can not answer your questions without the context of your entire iptables rule set. But yes, the DROP rule should be as early in the rule set as possible. Yes, in the end you might need help from your hoster, as there is always a way to overwhelm a computer with an attack like this.

Comment: What type of information you might need? I'll post it but tell me specific outputs you need.

Comment: Edit your question and add the output from `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L`.

Comment: OK added. See now.

Comment: Oh!. I did not realize that you don't actually have any iptables rules. (I suppose you are using `PREROUTING` or something again for your 1 rule.)

Comment: Yes i'am using now the rule in "PREROUTING" policy.

Comment: Doug Smythies, So i don't waste your time for now i told the my support to block source port 27015 (UDP) so they will do in a way that all the packets coming from this port be dropped before it reach my VPS. I'll see after what will happen if he will be able to flood me again or not and tell you here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simply to block that port in external firewall not from iptables. By blocking it in the external firewall the flooder now can't reach my VPS. You need to contact your support telling them to block source port "27015" UDP and they will do.

**iptables** not full effective but we can give it rating about **96 %**.

Thanks for **Doug Smythies** he try helping me :)